# PayPal - Updating Redirect Urls

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have initiated a Paypal Payment, got a token back.  PayPal has redirected back to my site using the URL I set in the `Payment`. From here I get the users shipping address, update the shipping costs and wait for the user to confirm payment.  However, at the same time (but in a separate function) I want to update the redirect urls (actually only the `return_url` if that's possible). I have the following code:

```
RedirectUrls redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
{
    cancel_url = ppmodel.CancelUrl + "&cancel=true",
    return_url = ppmodel.ReturnUrl + "?guid=" + basket.OrderGuid
};


PatchRequest pRequest = new PatchRequest();

Patch pUrls = new Patch
{
    op = "replace",
    path = "/redirect_urls",
    value = redirUrls
};
pRequest.Add(pUrls);
payment.Update(_apiContext, pRequest); --Error here
```

I am getting a server error 400 Bad Request.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?